# Oracle Statement does not count correctly

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a SQL-statement with a - for me not explainable - strange behaviour.
Perhaps you could find what's wrong:

When I use the statement

```
select count(*) from department
```

I got 2755 results

Using the following statement

```
select 
      building1.street, building1.streetno, building1.plz, building1.city, dept1.buildingid
  from 
      department dept1
    left join 
      supporter sup 
    on 
      dept.supporterid = sup.id
    left join 
      building building1
    on 
      sup.buildingid = building1.ibuildingid
  where 
      dept.usepostaladresssupporter = 1 
  union all
  select 
      building2.street, building2.streetno, building2.plz, building2.city, dept2.buildingid
  from 
      building building2
    right join 
      tueks_department dept2 
    on 
      dept2.buildingid = building2.ibuildingid
  where 
      dept2.usepostaladresssupporter = 0
```

I got 2755 results too.
But when I want to combine the two statements with a left join:

```
select count(*) from department
  left join
    (
      select 
          building1.street, building1.streetno, building1.plz, building1.city, dept1.buildingid
      from 
          department dept1
        left join 
          supporter sup 
        on 
          dept.supporterid = sup.id
        left join 
          building building1
        on 
          sup.buildingid = building1.ibuildingid
      where 
          dept.usepostaladresssupporter = 1 
      union all
      select 
          building2.street, building2.streetno, building2.plz, building2.city, dept2.buildingid
      from 
          building building2
        right join 
          tueks_department dept2 
        on 
          dept2.buildingid = building2.ibuildingid
      where 
          dept2.usepostaladresssupporter = 0
    ) postadress
  on
     department.buildingid = postadress.buildingid;
```

I got 3648513 results.

My expectation was, that I get only 2755 results.
Where's the mistake?

Thanks for help!

Comment: damn, my brain lost track after the 3rd join. what does a "not count" select on the inner select give you (row count speaking)... and is the buildingid unique?

Comment: Hi Najzero, yeah, I know, this statement is a little bit complex. If i count the inner select, I got 2755 results (with the union all). The buildingid is unique in the building-table

Comment: Buildingid is not a unique id of the rows in the two queries you are combining, therefore you will get the multiply effect that @LievenKeersmaekers describes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `buildingid` is not unique *(for my reasoning to hold true, it can't be unique)*

Imagine following simple tables

**TableA**

```
create TableA (name VARCHAR(32));
insert into TableA values ('Lieven');
insert into TableA values ('Lieven');
```

**TableB**

```
create TableB (name VARCHAR(32));
insert into TableB values ('Lieven');
insert into TableB values ('Lieven');
insert into TableB values ('AnyOtherValue');
```

**Select statement**

```
select * from TableA a left outer join TableB b on a.name = b.name
```

As **each** record of `TableA` is matched with **each** record of `TableB` where the `name` is equal, this will result in 4 records *(the AnyOtherValue is dissmissed as it doesn't match)*

- The first record of `TableA` is returned with two of three records of `TableB'
- The second record of `TableA` is returned with two of three records of `TableB'

Comment: So when I have 2755 records in TableA and 2755 records in TableB, I should get 7590025 results... but I've got 3648513 results, that's a little bit less than half of it.

Comment: @Tom - I see what you mean but you can't just multiply, it all depends on how many records match. I have altered my example a bit to show you that it's not necesarry just 2*3 *(or 2755*2755)*.

Comment: @Tom - that would be true if it was a cross join, forming a cartesian product of both tables; but you're still joining on `buildingid`, which gives fewer matches.

Comment: Hmm... okay, sounds logic. I tried to use the id of department, but then I got an error "missing keyword". But thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

The query

```
select 
      building1.street, building1.streetno, building1.plz, building1.city, dept1.buildingid
  from 
      department dept1
    left join 
      supporter sup 
    on 
      dept.supporterid = sup.id
    left join 
      building building1
    on 
      sup.buildingid = building1.ibuildingid
  where 
      dept.usepostaladresssupporter = 1 
  union all
  select 
      building2.street, building2.streetno, building2.plz, building2.city, dept2.buildingid
  from 
      building building2
    right join 
      tueks_department dept2 
    on 
      dept2.buildingid = building2.ibuildingid
  where 
      dept2.usepostaladresssupporter = 0
```

will return one row per department that has usepostaladresssupporter as either 0 or 1  (note that records with other values will not be included, this may or may not be a problem depending on the constrainst of this column).

The unique key of this query results is probably something like departmentid (you will need to include that column in your select criteria).

So the correct query should look something like this:

```
select * from department
  left join
    (
      select 
          building1.street, building1.streetno, building1.plz, building1.city, dept1.departmentid
      from 
          department dept1
        left join 
          supporter sup 
        on 
          dept.supporterid = sup.id
        left join 
          building building1
        on 
          sup.buildingid = building1.ibuildingid
      where 
          dept.usepostaladresssupporter = 1 
      union all
      select 
          building2.street, building2.streetno, building2.plz, building2.city, dept2.departmentid
      from 
          building building2
        right join 
          tueks_department dept2 
        on 
          dept2.buildingid = building2.ibuildingid
      where 
          dept2.usepostaladresssupporter = 0
    ) postadress
  on
     department.departmentid = postadress.departmentid;
```

Your query will go wrong on data something like this:

Departmentid    BuildingId    Name

1               1             Dept1

2               2             Dept2

3               2             Dept3

The multiplying effect is not quite equal to deptcount * deptcount, but rather it is buildingcount * buildingcount + deptcount - buildingcount

Comment: I tried to use the id, but the I got a "missing keyword"-error, but I won't give up ;-)